# How to add line feed to body text on MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using a MFMailComposeViewController to create a new email.

On the body text I want something like this:

> Hi,
>
> This application bla bla bla.
>
> To make this work you have to bla bla.
>
> Thanks.

So, we have four paragraphs of text and I want to give a space between them.

I am constructing the body text string like this:

```
NSString *body = @"Hi,\n\nThis application bla bla bla.\n\nTo make this work you have to bla boa.\n\nThanks\n\n";
```

Hoping \n would add a space between paragraphs.

I know I can make it work if I use `<br />`, making the email be HTML, but I want to create a plain text email for maximum compatibility.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you have made `isHTML:NO` in the below method. With `isHTML:NO`, `\n` should work fine.

```
NSString *body = @"Hi,\n\nThis application bla bla bla.\n\nTo make this work you have to bla boa.\n\nThanks\n\n";
[mailComposer setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];
```

Output:

> Hi,
>
> This application bla bla bla.
>
> To make this work you have to bla bla.
>
> Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A follow-up for iOS apps running on Apple Silicon Macs...  set isHTML:YES in order to get line breaks to appear when sending email from an iOS app on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this placeholder text:

```
let messageText = "Hi,</br>"
                + "This application bla bla bla.</br>"
                + "To make this work you have to bla bla.</br>"
                + "Thanks."
```

then you call the following function:

```
func contactUs() {
        let email = "your@email.com"
        let subject = "Email subject"
        let bodyText = messageText //The property that we created earlier
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mailComposerVC.delegate = self
            mailComposerVC.setToRecipients([email])
            mailComposerVC.setSubject(subject)
            mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(bodyText, isHTML: true)
            self.present(mailComposerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let coded = "mailto:\(email)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(bodyText)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
            if let emailURL = URL(string: coded!) {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(emailURL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(emailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: { (result) in
                        
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
```